# Я новичок в Golang, пытаюсь импортировать часть кода из другого пакета, который лежит в другой папке, но возникает ошибк

Tags: golang, импорт

Извиняюсь, если что-то криво запостил, я тут впервые

Я хочу импортировать пакет datafile из папки datafile из файла floats.go при написании когда VS code сам предложил мне привязать импортируемые файлы из папки, я нажал enter, чтобы строка сразу появилась в разделе import как я это обычно делал с другими библиотеками, но строка загорается красным, код не выполняется, не понимаю, что я делаю не так.

Сам проект простой, его аналог работал, когда всё было в одном файле, суть такая: я забираю данные из файла и преобразую их в числа, далее получаю среднее арифметическое. Но когда я попытался разделить код на разные части и распихать их по разным файлам что-то пошло не так.

Я пытался всячески менять путь папки, но это не помогло. Думаю, что возможно проблема в том, что мой исполняемый файл находится не в корневой папке языка GO, открывал терминал я через способ на картинке №3[[image: как я обычно открываю терминал для файла, может это неправильно?][1]] путь к файлам

```
  1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ5aO.png
  2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/USJ5K.png
  3 https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJzIL.png
  4 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqfsh.png
```

[Пакет, который я пытаюсь импортировать из соседней папки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJzIL.png)

[image: Основной файл]

Answer (score 0):

1. Перенести проект в GOPATH. import "test/datafile"
   Изменить GO111MODULE на auto -> go env -w GO111MODULE=auto
2. Если проект находится вне GOPATH. Сделать go mod init yourprojectname. Путь импорта import "test/datafile"
3. Модуль datafile может быть где угодно. Тогда
   3.1 Делаем go mod init datafile в datafile
   3.2 В файле go.mod главного проекта пишем нечто подобное:

   module mainprogram

   go 1.19

   require datafile v0.0.0

   replace datafile v0.0.0 => c:/Projects/datafile

   3.3 в корне проекта go mod tidy